# How to compile an app that requires EGL on OS X

Tags: macos, opengl, egl

I've got a big thirdparty library and I need to make it work on OS X. The library uses EGL for some purposes (texture reading AFAIR), but there is no libEGL in the system. I don't actually want to rewrite parts and remove EGL dependency.

Is there any ways to make it work?